# Deny read on unpublished posts firebase same collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a simple fireStore collection named `jokes` where there is a document per joke.
In a joke, there is a key `published: boolean`

So the idea is to have a single collection with jokes, but each document can be either published or unpublished. I would not like users to view unpublished jokes.

In my fireStore rules, i have the following:

```
match /jokes/{id} {
  allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/jokes/$(id)).data.published == true
}
```

In my application, I want users to be able to see only the published jokes, therefore i use the where

```
this.$fireStore.collection('jokes').where('published', '==', true).get()
```

When I do this, the console tells me i got insufficient permissions.

Is it possible to use this pattern, or do I have to use cloud functions to serve the published jokes? Or maybe a separate collection for unpublished ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `get()` in the rule for this, as the current document is already available as `resource`. In fact, that `get()` is the problem here, as the rules engine cannot statically evaluate that for all document in one go.

```
match /jokes/{id} {
  allow read: if resource.data.published == true
}
```

Also see the documentation on [securely querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query), specifically the section on [securing and querying documents based on a field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_a_field)